# DXGI_FORMAT_YUY2 textures return different RowPitch under Windows 8.1 and Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows-8.1, windows-10, directx-11

My build environment is as follows:
Windows 8.1, VS2012, desktop application built using windows 8.0 SDK and C++.

When I run my program on windows 8.1 the RowPitch prints 2560 but under windows 10 the same program prints 5120.

What am I doing wrong here?

Here is the code, Thanks for all the replies.

```
#include <d3d11.h>

static bool init_directx11(ID3D11Device **pDevice, ID3D11DeviceContext **pDeviceContext)
{
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevels[] = {D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0, D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1, D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0, D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_1};

    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevel;

    UINT createDeviceFlags = D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT;
    HRESULT hr = D3D11CreateDevice(NULL, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, NULL, createDeviceFlags, featureLevels, ARRAYSIZE(featureLevels), D3D11_SDK_VERSION, pDevice,
                                   &featureLevel, pDeviceContext);

    return SUCCEEDED(hr);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    ID3D11Device *pDevice = nullptr;
    ID3D11DeviceContext *pDeviceContext= nullptr;
    if (!init_directx11(&pDevice, &pDeviceContext))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC desc;
    ZeroMemory(&desc, sizeof(D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC));

    desc.ArraySize = 1;
    desc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
    desc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
    desc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_YUY2;
    desc.MipLevels = 1;
    desc.MiscFlags = 0;
    desc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    desc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
    desc.Width = 1280;
    desc.Height = 720;

    ID3D11Texture2D* pTexture2D = nullptr;
    HRESULT hr = pDevice->CreateTexture2D(&desc, NULL, &pTexture2D);

    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mappedResource;
    ZeroMemory(&mappedResource, sizeof(DXGI_MAPPED_RECT));
    hr = pDeviceContext->Map(pTexture2D, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0, &mappedResource);

    printf("RowPitch = %d\n", mappedResource.RowPitch);

    pDeviceContext->Unmap(pTexture2D, 0);


    pTexture2D->Release();
    pDeviceContext->Release();
    pDevice->Release();

    getchar();
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

> What am I doing wrong here?

This is not necessarily wrong. `RowPitch` depends on layout the hardware and driver assigned for the texture. The pitch might vary. You are supposed to read the pitch back once the resource is mapped, and use it respectively to read or write the data.

See [this thread and message](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/606100-solved-dx11-updating-texture-data/?view=findpost&p=4834406) for pitch use code snippet:

> The texture resource will have it's own pitch (the number of bytes in a row), which is probably different than the pitch of your source data. This pitch is given to you as the "RowPitch" member of D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE. So typically you do something like this:
>
> ```
> BYTE* mappedData = reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(mappedResource.pData);
> for(UINT i = 0; i < height; ++i)
> {
>   memcpy(mappedData, buffer, rowspan);
>   mappedData += mappedResource.RowPitch;
>   buffer += rowspan;
> }
> ```

Comment: As noted, it doesn't really matter because you should use the returned mapped values. I have noted this as an OS difference with the platform team.

Comment: After reading this post I did use the mapped values. However, when I copy my YUY2 data from a webcam to the texture (that returns twice the row pitch on Win10) then try to display that texture using the pixel shader, the contents of the image show up in their entirety but fill only half the rectangular area I display them on. This does not happen on Windows 8.1, the image displays correctly. I understand that there is padding involved but twice the padding?

Comment: Also according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd206750(v=vs.85).aspx the data in a YUY2 texture is supposed to be contiguous so my image must display correctly as it does on Win 8.1

Comment: The data does not have to be contiguous. Yes it is often contiguous, but in this particular case video adapter intentionally uses layout it chose for performance reasons, with padding and extended strides. You have to take it as offered. If the image does not show up well, then you possibly has another (even though possibly related) problem to deal with.

Comment: When I said contiguous I meant that I was copying 2560 bytes (my image is 1280x720) per row of 5120 bytes in the texture just as your link from the first post points out, but each row of data is contiguous, there are no gaps between pixels on the same row. However, once I start sampling this data in the pixel shader I get only half the screen with the image in its entirety but the colors are some what messed up. The same pixel shader works perfectly in Windows 8.1.